# How to add comments to folders using WebStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, development-environment, jetbrains-ide

I want to add some description to my folder, like here:

[image]

Can I do this simple using WebStorm?

Comment: You cannot. If you need to describe what some folders do to somebody else (or to yourself to check it later) make some `readme.md` or alike in your project root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in Webstorm, please vote for [IDEABKL-6362](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6362) to be notified on any progress with this request